# Can you figure out why this program is triggering a IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, exception, encryption, cryptography

all files in ~/Cipher/nsdl/crypto can be found [here](http://nsdeleon.wikispaces.com/file/detail/crypto.zip)
java files compiled with gcj, see compile.sh

```
nmint@nqmk-mint ~/Cipher/nsdl/crypto $ echo test | ./cryptTest encrypt deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef deadbeef Blowfish CBC > test
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: cipher is not for encrypting or decrypting
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(libgcj.so.81)
   at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(libgcj.so.81)
   at nsdl.crypto.BlockCrypt.encrypt(cryptTest)
   at nsdl.crypto.cryptTest.main(cryptTest)
```

BlockCrypt.java:

```
package nsdl.crypto;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class BlockCrypt {
Cipher ecipher;
Cipher dcipher;
byte[] keyBytes;
byte[] ivBytes;
SecretKey key;
AlgorithmParameterSpec iv;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

BlockCrypt(String keyStr, String ivStr, String algorithm, String mode) {
    try {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm + "/" + mode + "/PKCS5Padding");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm + "/" + mode + "/PKCS5Padding");

        keyBytes = hexStringToByteArray(keyStr);
        ivBytes = hexStringToByteArray(ivStr);

        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);
        iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // out: where the plaintext goes to become encrypted
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);

        // in: where the plaintext comes from
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // in: where the plaintext come from, decrypted on-the-fly
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);

        // out: where the plaintext goes
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
        + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
}
```

cryptTest.java:

```
package nsdl.crypto;

import nsdl.crypto.BlockCrypt;

public class cryptTest {

public static void main (String args[]) {
    if (args.length != 5) {
        System.err.println("Usage: cryptTest (encrypt|decrypt) key iv algorithm mode");
        System.err.println("Takes input from STDIN. Output goes to STDOUT.");
    } else {
        String operation = args[0];
        String key = args[1];
        String iv = args[2];
        String algorithm = args[3];
        String mode = args[4];
        BlockCrypt blockCrypt = new BlockCrypt(key, iv, algorithm, mode);
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt")) {
            blockCrypt.encrypt(System.in, System.out);
        } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("decrypt")) {
            blockCrypt.decrypt(System.in, System.out);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid operation. Use (encrypt|decrypt).");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It might help to know where the exception is thrown.

Comment: It says where it's thrown:  at nsdl.crypto.BlockCrypt.encrypt(cryptTest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cipher, `ecipher`, is not initialized, and it throws an `IllegalStateException` when you try to use it as if it were initialized in `ENCRYPT_MODE`.

Note your `catch` block in the constructor of `BlockCrypt`. It is catching an exception with no message, and printing "null" to `System.err`. Rather than aborting execution—perhaps by throwing an exception from the constructor—you keep sailing.

Replacing `System.err.println(e.getMessage())` with `e.printStackTrace()` or at least `System.err.println(e)` should give you more detail. My guess is that `ecipher.init()` is throwing an exception because you're providing a 32-bit IV instead of 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.
If I make sure the IV is 64bits, the program works perfectly!
You'll get in the credits when I finish my science fair project.
(I don't really know what else I can do to thank you - I'm only an eighth grader.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps looking at [the source for javax.crypto.Cipher](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/javax/crypto/Cipher-source.html) helps this make sense?  I couldn't really figure it out, even finding the error message in the source.  Good luck!